# Rails Paperclip images not showing up in on cloud9 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am using paperclip to upload images to a rails application on cloud9 virtual environment (ubuntu).  There is a Movie model and each movie object has an image associated to it.

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
    has_attached_file :movie_img, styles: { medium: "250x350>", thumb: "325x475>" }, default_url: "/images/style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :movie_img, content_type: '/\Aimage\/.*\Z/'
end
```

The view looks like this

```
    <% @movies.each do |movie| %>
            <%= image_tag movie.movie_img.url(:movie_index), class: "movie" %>
    <% end %>
```

But images are not showing up on the site.

The path to images in the generated html looks like this

> system/movies/movie_imgs/000/000/010/movie_index/fileName.jpg?1465401579
>   The images are present in the actual directory as I can see from the file explorer of Cloud9.

When I open this image address it shows the following error.

> No route matches [GET] "/system/movies/movie_imgs/000/000/011/movie_index/fileName.png"

Also in the config/environments/development.rb I have written the following line of code

```
  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"
```

because when I enter which convert in the terminal, the following shows up.

> /usr/bin/convert

Where am I going wrong? How can I make the images appear in the server?

**EDIT**
I have also generate necessary migration and my movie table looks like this.

```
create_table "movies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "director"
    t.date     "release_date"
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.string   "movie_img_file_name"
    t.string   "movie_img_content_type"
    t.integer  "movie_img_file_size"
    t.datetime "movie_img_updated_at"
```

end

Still images are not showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be declaring a view helper for sizing the image (:movie_index) that is not defined at the Movie model.

You need to declare the helper and the size for :movie_index at the model as such:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
    has_attached_file :movie_img, styles: { movie_index: "300x300>" medium: "250x350>", thumb: "325x475>" }, default_url: "/images/style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :movie_img, content_type: '/\Aimage\/.*\Z/'
end
```

**Edit:**

Make sure you have already generated the necessary migration:

```
rails g paperclip Movie movie_img
```

Be sure to read the [Paperclip documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).

Comment: I have already generated the necessary migration and I have added my schema in the question details. Please check it once. The images exist in that path but they are not visible in the site.

Comment: @YashSharma Did you add "movie_index: "300x300>" as I suggested?

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved the problem. Thanks a lot!!